# 'GL/glew.h' file not found

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to include glew and glfw in my c++ project, but when I try to run this code:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
```

it doesn't work. Here is my settings.json:

```
{
    "cmake.configureOnOpen": true,
    "C_Cpp.default.includePath": [
        "lib/glfw-3.4.bin.MACOS/include/",
        "lib/glew-2.1.0/include/"
    ]
```

and here is my c_cpp_properties.json:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${default}",
                "${workspaceFolder}",
                "${workspaceFolder}/lib/glfw-3.4.bin.MACOS/include",
                "${workspaceFolder}/lib/glew-2.1.0/include"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "macos-clang-arm64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

I'm getting the following error message: `'GL/glew.h' file not found`

Here is what my dircetory looks like:

[image]

Comment: Neither c_cpp_properties.json nor settings.json tune the compiler command. You missed to configure it in tasks.json.

Comment: @273K Thank you. How do I do this?

Comment: You probably wanted to start with the macOS documentation to understand what the json files do: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac)